# I am trying to figure out what these temporary variables mean

Tags: python

```
def genfibon(n):      #fib sequence until n
   a=1
   b=1
   for i in range n:
      yield a
      t=a
      a=b
      b=t+b
```

Can someone explain the t variable? It seems like `t=a` so then `a=b` and then `b=t` because `a=b` and `a=t`. How does `b=t+b`?

Comment: I fixed the indentation of the code. But, in my opinion, this more of an  algorithmic question than [what should be asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: `t` is the *old* value of `a`, that is before it was assigned to `b`.

Comment: @zondo It is a little bit confusing if you do not know how yield works...

Comment: they mean someone needs to learn how to name variables descriptively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say a = 2 and b = 3.

```
t = a # now t = 2
a = b # now a = 3, but t is unchanged
b = t + b # now b = 5
```

The key is that second part. `t = a` means `t` gets the same value as `a`. It does not mean that `t` and `a` are now both the same thing.

You might try this in a Python prompt:

```
a = 3
b = a
a = 5
print(b) # still 3
```

Comment: So it is like a local variable?

Is it local if the variable it isn't like in a defined function?

Comment: Yes, it's a local variable, *because* it's declared in a function. (Outside a function/class, you would call it a global variable.)

Answer (score 2):

It's called swapping of variables. how do you replace the values of variables?

as @smarx said, when `a = 2` and `b = 3`, how do you make it `a = 3` and `b = 2`?

when you do `a = 3`, the old value of a(2) is lost so you wont know what to set b with. so we store this in a temporary variable(t).

so,

```
t = a //(saves 2 in t)
a = b //(now both a and b have same values)
b = t //(b gets the old value of a)
// now a = old value of b 
// and b = old value of a.
```

voila, the variables are swapped.

Well, that goes for swapping. which is only partly used in this code. the last statement `b = t + b` what the code is doing is, adding the old value of a with b(rather than replacing it). why? you get the next number in a fibonacci sequence by adding the previous 2.

2, 3, 5 is a fibonacci sequence since 5 = 2 + 3(given 2 and 3 are seed values). that's exactly what this code is doing.

Comment: FYI, in Python you can just do `a, b = b, a`. :-) But that doesn't help explain this code.

Comment: @smarx indeed. also, i made a mistake here. the code isn't to swap variables. it's to generate fibonacci sequence, that's why in the end, b = t + b. i'll update the answer.

Comment: Also, this code doesn't actually do a swap. But `a, b = b, a + b` would work.

Answer (score 2):

In your first run

```
yield a # will return 1 
t = a  # which is 1
a = b  # which is 1
b = t + b  # which is 2 as t = 1 and b = 1
```

In your 2nd run

```
yield a # will return 1 
t = a  # which is 1
a = b  # which is 2
b = t + b  # which is 3 as t = 1 and b = 2
```

In your 3rd run

```
yield a # will return 2 
t = a  # which is 2
a = b  # which is 3
b = t + b  # which is 5 as t = 2 and b = 3
```

In your 4th run

```
yield a # will return 3 
t = a  # which is 3
a = b  # which is 5
b = t + b  # which is 8 as t = 3 and b = 5
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

Let us go statement by statement.

1. `t=a` means value of `a` is stored in `t`.
2. `a=b` means value of `b` is stored in `a`. (Thus `a` now contains the next element in the series)
3. `b=t+b` means value of `b` is now `t + b` which means `a+b` since `t` now contains the value of `a` (According to first step).